# Angular ng-repeat depending on search results

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, search

I'm very new angular and while I like it so far, I have run into a little problem with my first real case. I have a .json file of staff member's information. I also have a global search run by Google's Search Appliance that just goes through pages. Ideally when a user searches for a key term if it matches any names in my .json file I would like to display their info (a link to their full profile would also come from the .json) separate from the search results.

So far I have been able to display the .json on the page using ng-repeat and sort/limit the quantity that get displayed. I'm guessing I would have to parse the url for the search term used somehow. Is this functionality even possible with angular?

Any leads or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) object. This gives you all url params. The sort|limit functionality is also right way to go about searching a JSON object.

Comment: You could build a `Staff` controller to import and house the JSON data, and then based on the search, populate a `$scope.staffMatched` variable and use `ng-repeat` on that.

Comment: @Jonn That sounds like pretty much what I have. Thanks for the suggestion! What is the angular directive to "match" from the JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Angular, but go ahead and give this a shot.  Note that it is dependent on `angular-resources.js`.

The idea is to make a factory that populates the data, and then a controller that will interact with the DOM.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('StaffData', function($http){
  return {
    getData : function() { //Load your json file
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "staff.json"
      }).success(function(staff) { return staff; })  //Return the staff data
      .error(function(e) { console.log(e); return []; });  //An error occurred
    }
});

myApp.controller('StaffSearch', function($scope, StaffData){
  var allStaff = StaffData.getData();
  $scope.staffMatched = refine(allStaff);

}

function refine(staff) {
  var matches = [];
  //Implement search algorithm here
  return matches;
}
```

And then in the HTML,

```
<div ng-controller="StaffData">
  <div ng-repeat"member in staffMatched"> {{member.name}} </div>
</div>
```

Instead of using the `refine` function, try to use the [Angular's filter functions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).